# Three odd objects run in a race. How did they fare? How was the chase?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, poetry

Seven minutes, turn it on
Put it under, turn it off
Dice it, chop it, lay it out
Add meat and bun and pour it out

It's an old puzzle
But I won't be a muzzle
Can you guess what they are
And how they ran hard?

Can you discover can you compare
What appliance was veg under there
What vegetable was under chef's care
What condiment made the dish so fair

And if all 3 were running in a race
Who came first, second, third in the chase
If you can figure it out in a moment
You'll win all the points and have fun being chosen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It feels like a classic pun. The three competitors were:

> Tap, lettuce, tomato sauce

With the result

> Lettuce, tap, tomato sauce

Because

> The tap was running, but the lettuce was a head and the sauce needed to ketchup.

Comment: You got it! Great job